# How to turn on auto-completion for Unity3d classes in Monodevelop in Linux?

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, game-development

Long time ago Unity3d was installed with Monodevelop and integration was good.
Auto-completion for Unity3d classes in Monodevelop worked perfect.
Now we have to install Monodevelop seperatly and there is no Auto-completion for Unity classes at all.
(Linux computer)